Order number should be populated serially
I have a requirement where orders are created by our users every minute. Once an order is created, it is in stage = draft. It then moves from Draft --> Submitted --> Fulfilled. Once it moves from Draft --> Submitted, I want a field OrderNumber to be populated in a ABC-00001 format in a sequential way. Meaning 1st order moved from Draft --> submitted should be ABC-00001, then next order moved as ABC-00002. How do I achieve this requirement ? I am thinking a trigger to accomplish this, but how is the order maintained ? Please advise.

A trigger probably would be the way to go, but the other considerations you need to make (what if the operation fails? how do you handle two orders that come in within a few milliseconds of one another? what about orders that get canceled?) is where the challenge is. Is there a particular reason why you absolutely must have sequential numbers ("because it looks better" isn't a compelling reason)? If "strictly increasing numbers" is good enough, then simply using an autonumber field ought to get you there with 0 code.

Thanks for the response. I can use an autonumber but it gets populated on create and stage = draft, but business specifically wanted to only populate it when stage is moved from draft to submitted.

Order.OrderNumber is an OOTB AutoNumber field. I suggest you create a custom field call OrderMumber_Suffix__c that increments 0..1..2. Then create a formula field that concatenates Order.OrderNumber with Order_Number_Suffix__c

But Order.OrderNumber gets populated on create of an order. I want my autoNumber field to start populating sequentially only when stage is moved from Draft -> Submitted.

Then have the suffix go from Draft->1->2; I agree with Derek that rather than trying to workaround the complexites of your own custom code-driven numbering scheme; exploit the OOTB OrderNumber field (which gets displayed in lookup picklists)

While possible with code, this is one of the situations where even I (a generally "I'd rather do it in code" guy) don't think that doing this through code is worth it. Handling concurrency, not using unnecessary queries, etc... is just too much work for what's being requested here.
I would seriously consider just using an autonumber field (which gets you strictly increasing numbers).
If you only want to display it after a certain stage (or really any other simple criteria), then simply don't add that autonumber field to page layout(s). Instead, create a formula field (which would be on the page layout) where you can check for your target criteria, then pull the value from the autonumber field (and return null/empty string when the criteria is false).
If you're asked for more than that, then the appropriate response for your boss/management/the c-suite would probably be something along the lines of

We have a simple solution already
How many thousands of dollars and weeks of development and testing do you want to allocate to get this from 95% to 99%?

